# Different output between release and Debug

Tags: c++

I can't figure this one out. I have a c++ Application that works in Debug mode exactly as expected:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void truncateServer(std::string inString);
int _tmain(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* server = argv[1];

    truncateServer(server);
}

void truncateServer(std::string inString)
{
    std::string server = "";
    int whackCount = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inString.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = inString[i];

        if (whackCount < 3)
        {
            if (c == '\\') whackCount++;
            else
            server += c;
        }

    }

    cout << server;

}
```

For example if I call the server I want via its UNC path `\\serverName\Share\` in the debug it gives me exactly what I want: `servername`

However, if I use the release build I get nothing:

[image: Bad Output]

I deleted the release output folder, but the issue is exactly the same. I can only assume there is some other difference between the release and build applications that is exposing a major issue with my code? Or another difference between the outputs I need to account for.

What do I need to do to get the expected output?

Comment: hmm, is your debug build ANSI and your release build UNICODE ? Also, the correct declaration is: `int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])`  because in Unicode builds, wide characters are used.

Comment: Can you add logging in the release build to show you whether you're getting expected values at various points?

Comment: Don't use `_tmain`.  For the reasons @SirDarius states: you don't know what it will end up as.

Comment: @SirDarius the project is built in multibyte, to my knowledge. Config - General Properties - Advanced. Is there another place to check on the release?

Comment: A shot in the dark (and unlikely) ... but maybe there is something odd with the console.  Maybe try adding ` << endl;` to your `cout` statement.

Comment: @SirDarius and JamesKanze... That was it. Can I get that as an answer. All I had to do was change the _tmain() to int main...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your Debug build is set as Ansi and your release build as Unicode.

The `_tmain` declaration is a Visual Studio specific macro which changes the entry point of your application depending on the used charset.

For ANSI it maps to `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` .
For Unicode it maps to `int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])`.

By using the `char` type as parameter to _tmain, you cause the compiler to use the wrong type when using an Unicode build, and so end up with a `'\0'` character as first byte, which std::string can't handle.

In your case, I recommend sticking to `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` as it will work in all cases, especially with std::string which use chars.

Also, it is more portable across compilers and operating systems.